# Installing app via eclipse ADT vs Installing app using installer from bin folder or generated signed/unsigned apk file

Tags: android, installation, android-lifecycle

I've been having a huge problem regarding installation of the application. When I try to install it via eclipse ADT (Connecting via usb cable and press run), the app starts and when I press home and go back immediately to the app it displays my last activity. But when I install the app from the bin folder or the generated signed and unsigned installer, the app closes. Closes meaning when I start the app, click home button and return again, the app seems to have restarted. I tried navigating to other pages expecting that when I hit home and return back to the app, I will be brought back to the page prior clicking the home button. I really don't think this is code related. Maybe in the manifest? Here is it if it would help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nesv.landstar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.DriverLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.nesv.landstar.LandstarPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.nesv.landstar.BGService"></service>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I didn't expect this kind of behavior but all my apps that have been installed outside the ADT meaning installer from the bin folder and generated signed/unsidgned installer are acting this way. Any ideas guys? Every comments and suggestions will be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, not really the  an answer but have a look at developer options of your phone. I am not sure but i think, when you install by the "bin way" the phone acts normally. It destroys activity because system needs memory. It dosen't in "eclipse way" may be because of dev options. Have you tried testing the "bin way" by freeing as much as possible ram on the phone ? It may have a different beahvior too.

Comment: I just started the app, clicked home button and right after that I get back to the application. That really consumed a lot of memory for it to be destroyed? Anyways, thanks for the suggestion! I will try that. Where can I find the developer options in my gingerbread phone? I only have development inside the application on settings. This is where I enable debug mode.

Comment: Memory footprint depends on your app (Bitmap background , icons ...) images you load at runtime. It depends also of available memory when you run the app.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem freeing up some RAM. My app is the only thing running

Comment: Have a look at this for saving state of Activities http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Activity_State_Changes_-_An_Example_Application

Comment: Anyway no problem with your manifest. As @Code_Yoga suggested you can add some log in the lifecycle methods and see what happens and when. You should really consider to look at developer options of your phone to see if an option is not blocking the behaviour observed by installing the bin.

Comment: I have logs on my onPause and etc. onDestory doesn't seem to kick. I do not know why. There are only three things that my development options have. Usb debugging, mock locations and keep awake. I don't think any of this blocks the app. And the problem is, this also happenson other devices. How come it is like that when my app is not designed to behave like this.